# Matlab predict function not working

Tags: matlab, svm, training-data

I am trying to train a linear SVM on a data which has 100 dimensions. I have 80 instances for training. I train the SVM using `fitcsvm` function in MATLAB and check the function using `predict` on the training data. When I classify the training data with the SVM all the data points are being classified into only one class.

```
SVM = fitcsvm(votes,b,'ClassNames',unique(b)');
predict(SVM,votes);
```

This gives outputs as all 0's which corresponds to 0th class. `b` contains 1's and 0's indicating the class to which each data point belongs. 
The data used, i.e. matrix `votes` and vector `b` are given the following [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B7D85BA25292B9A6!1623&authkey=!AJLSUEwifltpxxg&ithint=file%2cmat)

Comment: Of course you can't train an SVM using 100 classes with only 80 training points.

Comment: @Adriaan Thanx small things just escape attentions

Comment: @Adriaan looks like b contains only two classes, 80 is the size of the training set and 100 is the feature dim.

Comment: @gregswiss my bad, I mixed up terms. Still, using 80 points to split based on 100 features still needs quite the regularisation, which will go badly when using regularised data for a SVM.

Comment: with some care it should be possible to keep overfitting under control...

Comment: @Adriaan I recomputed new data points which have 40 dimensions and 80 data points. And I am facing same problem. data used [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B7D85BA25292B9A6!1624&authkey=!AF40bqFmkMsWnVA&ithint=file%2cmat)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you use a non-linear kernel, such as a gaussian kernel and that the parameters of the kernel are tweaked. Just as a starting point:

```
SVM = fitcsvm(votes,b,'KernelFunction','RBF', 'KernelScale','auto');
bp = predict(SVM,votes);
```

that said you should split your set in a training set and a testing set, otherwise you risk overfitting

Comment: +1, The fix to [my problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267100/svm-prediction-does-not-predict-ok-although-the-support-vectors-are-valid).