# SVM prediction does not predict OK although the support vectors are valid

Tags: matlab, classification, svm, prediction

I have a following(*fig 1*) **unlabeled** training set which I am trying to detect the outliers, have come up with a procedure to label the data with `0:normal data` and `1:outlier` and want to train it with SVM.
I followed [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitcsvm.html) instructions to train the SVM's model but when I am trying to `predict` the labels of **same** data I have trained the SVM it does not predict any(*fig 2*)!

### fig 1: the support vectors after training

[image]

### fig 2: the prediction of SVM model on the same data it has been training with

[image]

The output of prediction is not supposed to look like this!
The code I have used for prediction is:

```
out = predict(model, data');
```

### Question:

What is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it worth, I have found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33303595/2787924) to my question and now its working fine.

The result of prediction after using a non-linear kernel, but I don't know why this happened?
[image]